# server installer for 22.04: can not select boot drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi, gpt

I am providing an ubuntu installer from PXE boot with uefi/grub following [this guide](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510), except I have to use grub because syslinux/pxeboot doesn't run on uefi. The installer boots fine.

I the drive I want to use uses a gpt partition table. I had previously installed a different linux and my current disk layout is as such.

- partition 1, 2 and 3 are used for windows.
- partition 4 is EFI and should be mounted on /boot/efi
- partition 5 is btrfs and was previously used to mount / and /home on the previous system, which is what I want to do again. It should be reformatted for that task.
- partition 6 is swap
- partition 7 is where grub is installed and should be reformatted to be mounted as /boot.

So in the installer I continue to the point where to select the disk to use and I pick custom layout. I configure the partitions to be used as such:

- partition 4, vfat, mount as /boot/efi
- partition 5, reformat btrfs, mount as /
- partition 6, swap
- partition 7, reformat ext4, mount as /boot

However the installer says at the top that

> To continue you need to: Select a bot disk

However when I go to the device the option to "Use As Boot Device" is grayed out. Reformatting the disk with a new partition table is not an option as that would delete my windows partions as well.

The drive was originally using an msdos partition table, but I converted it using gdisk, following [this guide](https://recoverit.wondershare.com/partition-tips/convert-mbr-to-gpt-linux.html), so maybe that is the cause of the problem? But the other linux installed just fine with the graphical installer. Grub's osprobe didn't detect windows after the conversion so I had to add it manually at the time and for windows I had to fix it's booting so it used the new efi partition (partition 4).

I have found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1969822), which seems to be a similar issue, but it appears that this person is using an MBR partition table because his fdisk has option `a` to toggle bootable for his partitions.

How do I proceed with the installation without altering partitions 1,2,3 and 4?

**Edit**

I have since moved on to installing ubuntu mate with the graphical installer. This worked fine. I can however not accept any answers since the problem is resolved in a different way.

I believe the issue might have been caused by selecting vfat/fat32 for the efi partition, since there was a dedicated EFI selection in the graphical installer, which also warned me about not having one.